# jqgrid - Drag columns past edge of visible columns in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with a large number of columns, so not all of them are visible on the screen at once. If I want to drag the first column all the way to the end in IE, I have to drag to the edge, drop, drag to the edge, drop... etc. In other browsers, I am able to drag to the edge and hold it there, and the columns continue scrolling by until it gets to the end. Anyone know how to recreate this for IE?